# When browsing questions, back button always returns to page 1

Tags: bug, new-nav, question-lists, back-button

1. Go to the list of questions (any tab)
2. Click on page *X* (other than the first)
3. Select a question
4. Click the browser's back button

You will now be back on page 1 of the list, instead of page *X* (which would be the expected behavior).

Apparently, this only happens for question lists on StackOverflow. The back button works as expected for user lists and tag lists, as well as for question lists on other SE sites.

I'm guessing this bug happens because switching pages in SO's question list is done through dynamic in-place updates rather than actual links.

My browser is Chrome version 47.

Comment: Probably the new nav doesn't change the URL, so this is just another downside of it, one of many. You can opt out of it, and enjoy some more weeks/months of bug-less navigation. :)

Comment: cross-site dupe on MSO:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313878/browser-history-pagination-doesnt-remember-the-page-i-was-at-when-navigating-b